# Получить список из базы даннх отвечающий опредленному критерию

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Есть база данных на MySQL, в базе присутствует таблица `place`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данной таблице отвечает класс:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "place" )
public class PlaceTable {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "idplace" )
    private int placeId;

    @Column( name = "idparking")
    private String parkingId;

    @Column( name = "car" )
    private boolean flagCar;

    @Column( name = "bike" )
    private boolean flagBike;

    @Column( name = "truck" )
    private boolean flagTruck;

    @Column( name = "bus" )
    private boolean flagBus;

    @Column( name = "flag" )
    private boolean empty;

    @Column( name = "idcar" )
    private String carId;

    @Column( name = "timeBegin")
    private int timeBegin;

    public PlaceTable() {

    }
    .....
```

Необходимо получить из данной таблицы все строки, у которых в `idparking` стоит `P1` и запаковать в `ArrayList<PlaceTable>`

Получение данных такого типа я организовал через метод:

```
public ArrayList< PlaceTable> getWithCriteria( String field, String value ) throws HibernateException{
            Criteria placeCriteria = session.createCriteria(PlaceTable.class);
            placeCriteria.add( Restrictions.eq( field, value ));

            return ( ArrayList<PlaceTable> ) placeCriteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

в `field` подаю `parkingId`, в `value` - `P1`, но возращается `null`.
Возможно это связано что `createCriteria` `@Deprecated`, но замену данному методу не нашел.

Comment: В `field` надо подавать имя поля - parkingId, а на колонки в базе.

Comment: Да, я его и подаю, ощибся при написании вопроса